# NAN loss tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan, conv-neural-network

I am training a bounding box regression problem and using the coordinate component of the loss function described in the [YOLO paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf).

Method 1: Used a HOG feature vector as input to an ANN. Same loss function. Gave me a good model.

Method 2: Used images as input to a CNN. Final layer remains same as in method 1. Same loss function as well. But I am facing as issue with the loss being calculated. It is printing nan loss for training, dev and test, from the first epoch itself.

How do I go about making the CNN work, when the same loss function works with the ANN perfectly well? And what could be the reason for such an occurrence? I would like to be able to use the same loss function.

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the loss function is well implemented, from my experience problems with the loss are usually related either to bad input data (i.e. due to some data augmentation operation or some other mistakes your data look really bad), or your learning rate is too high. Try reducing the learning rate; if this doesn't work make a good debug and make sure that the data are "exactly" as you expect just before they are fed into the neural net.

Comment: I have tried all these. My learning rate is 10e-4. Data is correct, along with the corresponding labels. The loss function uses square root operation, and final layer activation is sigmoid. This didn't affect the ANN's training, but seems to have a huge impact on the CNN's training